# Android Studio Strings preview xml doesn't look right

Tags: android, xml, string, layout

I'm making a recipe app and when i write the recipe in the strings file then create the layout xml file and add the string to it, it doesn't look right. everything is just run on sentences even though i set the font and to enter each line in the strings file, it just doesn't preview that way. when i compile it and send it to my phone, it looks right so it's something with the android studio preview. here is a pic showing what it's doing because It's a little hard to explain. thanks for the help! [strings preview isn't right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5Nr5.png)

Comment: please include enough information for others to recreate the issue

Comment: their wasn't much info to include because it seemed to just happen after an update